# 2D plot using 1D arrays without griddata()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the function of two variables using `matplotlib`. The function is stored in three 1d arrays `X`, `Y` and `F` corresponding to x-coordinate, y-coordinate and the value of the function. Is it possible to plot these data as a contour plot? Before I saw the solution with `griddata()`, but I would like to avoid interpolating since x and y coordinates are already well defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120222/matplotlib-imshow-with-irregular-spaced-data-points

Comment: There the function griddata() has been used. I can build any distribution of coordinates in arrays X and Y including the regular uniform one, so I would like to avoid additional interpolating. Therefore, that link does not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [the contour demo of the matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html). Since you say you can calculate your function `F` exactly at any given point:

```
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
F = your_function(X.ravel(), Y.ravel())
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, F.reshape(X.shape))
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

Comment: What is the difference between Z and F? In my case, F is the one-dimensional array

Comment: @freude `Z` was a typo, should be `F`. You have to reshape your data to a 2D grid, see my edit on how to go about that.