# Plot a color map with abscess of different "bin"

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, colormap

I take an exemple from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41963296/6476722) to explain what I want to do:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

xs0 = [1,4,0.5,2,5,10,33,0.04]
ys0 = [2,5,44,0.33,2,14,20,0.03]
zs0 = [0.77, 0.88, 0.65, 0.55, 0.89, 0.9, 0.8,0.95]

N = 30j
extent = (np.min(xs0),np.max(xs0),np.min(ys0),np.max(ys0))  
xs,ys = np.mgrid[extent[0]:extent[1]:N, extent[2]:extent[3]:N]    
resampled = griddata(xs0, ys0, zs0, xs, ys, interp='linear')   
plt.imshow(np.fliplr(resampled).T, extent=extent,interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6erOT.png)

But there are many problems I do not success to solve:

- It's impossible to modify the length of the x  abscessas regard to y one. It's a big issue when you have orders of magnitude between the x and y datas.
- If I had `color= 'bwr'` in the imshow function, it doesn't work ! I don't understand why.
- Most important point: How can we fix a certain bin for the x abscess, and an other one for the y ? In my measurement I was taking 800 points for each sweeps (y abscess) but for only 50 different x values. That's a problem. I would like to be able to choose them independently, without any interpolation between two different x values. I can change `xs,ys = np.mgrid[extent[0]:extent[1]:N, extent[2]:extent[3]:N]` by `xs,ys = np.mgrid[extent[0]:extent[1]:N, extent[2]:extent[3]:M]` and create a `N = 30j` and `M = 300j` but that's not convinient...
- And a last question: what is this `N = 30j` ? Why not just `N = 30` ?!

Thanks a lot for your help ! As you can see, I am a little bit lost... 
(of course, do not feel obliged to use this code... I just have a X,Y,Z data I want to plot)